# iOS Firebase crashlytics show crash in dashboard but no reports

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have followed the guide and implemented everything that is needed to integrate firebase crashlytics. I have forced to crash my app for a couple of times and I'm not able to see any crash reports in the crashlytics tab. I do however see the number of crashes on the project overview(1 day after the crash happens) but when I click on it to view more detail it shows no crash. There is also no missing dsym in the dsyms tab.

I have pods

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.7'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.2'
```

The run script for upload dsym shows

> 2018-06-18 17:00:52.102 uploadDSYM[39595:428827] Fabric.framework/run 1.7.0 (208)
>
> 2018-06-18 17:00:52.108 uploadDSYM[39595:428827] Firebase mode detected.
>
> 2018-06-18 17:00:52.108 uploadDSYM[39595:428827] Using API Key: "xxxxxxxx"
>
> 2018-06-18 17:00:52.108 uploadDSYM[39595:428827] Launched uploader in validation mode

After the crash I also get a message saying

```
upload submission successful
```

But there is just no reports on firebase dashboard under crashlytics.

Comment: Hi Paul from Crashlytics here. I think this question requires more specific details about your implementation, logs, and code, and would be better served via our Troubleshooting support channel: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/?category=troubleshooting.